# Angular 2 - Typescript | variable is not usable in other function

Tags: javascript, function, typescript, angular, components

This is my first post, so go gentle!

I just started TS & Angular 2 a couple of days ago. Now I've run in to a problem that I find strange.

This is my code:

```
import ...

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
    imageArray : any;
    private _sessionToken : string;
    res: any;

constructor( private _http: Http) {

}

getUser():Promise<any> {
    console.log("Getting Post");
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-Client-Token', 'XXXXXXXX');
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    var data = JSON.stringify({
        "login": "XXXXXX",
        "password": "XXXXXXX"
    });

    return this._http.post('INSERT REST API', data, {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .map(this.doStuff)
        .toPromise()
}

doStuff(res) {
    this._sessionToken = res.token;
    console.log(this._sessionToken) ==> THIS WORKS !!!!! / EXISTS

}
getFilesForJob(jobId : string):Promise<any> {
    console.log(this._sessionToken); ==> THIS DOES NOT WORK !!!! / UNDEFIEND
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('X-Client-Token', 'XXXX');
    headers.append('X-Session-Token', this._sessionToken);
    headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
    return this._http.get('INSERT RESTFULL API' + jobId + '/files', {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .toPromise();
}
```

So,

the problem is that I can not get `'this._sessionToken'` back in `getFilesForJob()` this function is called after the login function is complete, and the token is set.

But when i log out `this._sessionToken` inside the `doStuff()` i do get my session token back.

when i log it out in `getFilesForJob()` i get undefined back. but the calls are made after each other.

Does angular 2 / typescript use instances of components? That would be my explanation why this does not work. But how do i fix it ?
What am I doing wrong here ? Is this something about Private / Public ?

Thank you !

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/lennartquerter/pfvtLudc/ doesnt work ofc, but this is the best way to show the code !

Comment: Both are different functions, and both different function do have their own scope, so this scope of both is different, so you can't get that this._sessionToken in both function, as both references to the other variables .. either you can use global variable, or make doStuff function to return the token ... or you need to somehow call them under the same scopee..

Comment: Thats not true because `private _sessionToken : string;` is a private var of the class HttpService. I found my problem and it was because I used a wrong way to call the function 'doStuff'. `.map(this.doStuff)` should be `.map(res => this.doStuff(res))`. This solves the problem !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there's a few things that could be at play here. How is `getFilesForJob` being called? The most likely scenario is that `this` is not set properly. Try setting a `debugger` before this line:

```
console.log(this._sessionToken); ==> THIS DOES NOT WORK !!!! / UNDEFIEND
```

and seeing if `this: HttpService` with all it's methods defined. If it's not, you've lost your scoping to `this` and there are a number of ways you could make sure `this` is bound to the `HttpService`—but it depends on how this method is being called.

Also, have you created an instance of this class? If you haven't—and you are calling this class externally, i.e. `HttpService.getFilesForJob()`, then you must prefix the method as `static`.

Comment: this is how the jobs are `
     constructor(private _httpService : HttpService) {
  this._httpService.getUser()
   .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    this.getImageList();
   });
 }

 getImageList = function () {
  this._httpService.getFilesForJob('353737')
   .then(res => this.imageListSetup(res));
 };`
this in debugger is HttpService. how do i prefix a method as static ? in the HttpService itself?

Thanks for your reply !

Comment: made a jsfiddle, but it doesnt work, just to explain how it works... 

https://jsfiddle.net/lennartquerter/pfvtLudc/